# d3 complex data, updating for existing nodes

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I searched the net lot and could not get any answered to fix.

Issue: I have complex data to represent the node in d3. based node value i will put the node label. There is sever running in the back end to generate the nodes and links and provides json. Based on the logic, the nodes name will change. Every 5 sec, the browser will make Ajax call and get the nodes and links json data. When ever the nodes name changes, it is not getting updated as per the new data.

D3 Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.node circle {
  cursor: pointer;
  stroke: #3182bd;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  pointer-events: none;
  text-anchor: middle;
}

line.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #9ecae1;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.overlay {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}


</style>
<body>
<p><h1>Topology View</h1>
<button id = "refresh" type="button" onclick="refresh()" >Refresh</button></p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var nodes ;
var links;
var width = window.innerWidth-30,
    height = window.innerHeight-140,
    root;
document.getElementById("refresh").disabled  = false;

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .linkDistance(100)
    .charge(-120)
    .gravity(.03)
    .size([width, height])
    .on("tick", tick);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .style("border", "1px solid black")
    .attr("height", height);

var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
  node = svg.selectAll(".node");

d3.json("topoJson.json", function(error, json) {
  if (error) throw error;

  root = json;
  update();

});

function update() {
  nodes = root.nodes;
  links = root.links;

  // Restart the force layout.
  force
      .nodes(nodes)
      .links(links)
      .start();

  // Update links.
  link = link.data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  link.exit().remove();

  link.enter().insert("line", ".node")
      .attr("class", "link");

  // Update nodes.
  node = node.data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id; });

  node.exit().remove();


  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .call(force.drag);

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
            .attr("r", 20)
            .attr("id", function(d) { return d.id; });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  node.select("circle")
      .style("fill", color);
}

function tick() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
}

function color(d) {
  return d.type == 'S' ? "#c6dbef": "#fd8d3c";
 }

function refresh() {
d3.json("topoJson.json", function(error, json) {
  if (error) throw error;

  root = json;
  update();
console.log(root);
});
}
</script>
```

On Refresh, actually data has to come from server, but here i have made it read from a file. The change in the json is not reflected.
Every time before i click refresh, i change the json in the file. the change will be name of the node. That name should reflect in the d3 node text. I could see the change in the console.log but not in the d3 node name.

topoJson.json

```
{
  "nodes": [
    {
      "type": "S",
      "id": "1",
      "name": "100"
    },
    {
      "type": "S",
      "id": "2",
      "name": "2"
    },
    {
      "type": "S",
      "id": "3",
      "name": "3"
    },
    {
      "type": "S",
      "id": "4",
      "name": "4"
    },
    {
      "type": "S",
      "id": "5",
      "name": "5"
    },
    {
      "type": "S",
      "id": "6",
      "name": "6"
    },
    {
      "type": "S",
      "id": "7",
      "name": "7"
    },
    {
      "type": "S",
      "id": "8",
      "name": "8"
    },
    {
      "type": "S",
      "id": "9",
      "name": "9"
    },
    {
      "type": "S",
      "id": "10",
      "name": "10"
    },
    {
      "id": "10.10.0.5",
      "name": "h5"
    },
    {
      "id": "10.10.0.3",
      "name": "h3"
    }
  ],
  "links": [
    {
      "source": 2,
      "target": 10
    },
    {
      "source": 2,
      "target": 11
    },
    {
      "source": 2,
      "target": 0
    },
    {
      "source": 3,
      "target": 5
    },
    {
      "source": 8,
      "target": 9
    },
    {
      "source": 5,
      "target": 6
    },
    {
      "source": 7,
      "target": 1
    },
    {
      "source": 1,
      "target": 3
    },
    {
      "source": 0,
      "target": 7
    },
    {
      "source": 6,
      "target": 8
    },
    {
      "source": 9,
      "target": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

I have created a fiddle. click the refresh to load the topology and click the change to make the change and click gain refresh.

http://jsfiddle.net/pkolanda/hmob49p3/21/

Basically in the change i am changing the name.

Please help me in fixing the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the update selection. The `enter()` selection identifies DOM nodes that need to be added, and the `exit()` selection identifies DOM nodes that need to be removed. What you want (for this question) are the DOM nodes that need to be updated. That's what the [`data()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data) function returns. Without digging into your code too deeply, something like the following should work:

```
node = node.data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id; });

node.select("text")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g") // ...
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen Thomas. actually i was doing that in my actual code. in this code, your solution worked. let me find out what is actual mistake i have done and will update the thread

Comment: I had missed a semi colon after the return statement in the function id of the nodes. Will that cause such a problem ? node.data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id }); . This is only mistake i could find in my main code